# Link generates https:// protocol when link should be http://

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I've got this weird problem on one of my Wordpress sites and I hope you all could help out.

I have a this Wordpress site set-up and working correct. It has a SSL certificate so the URL is `https://www.example.com`.

Now if I add a link to one of my pages like this `http://www.example_2.com` it automatically changes the link to the `https://` protocol. Which I find really strange because the link is literally `<a href="http://www.example_2.com">`.

Does anyone know why the link becomes `https://` instead of the normal `http://` protocol? Because my link is now giving an error when I click on the link and get send to the linked site.

I have googled this issue but it only give me results for how to configure your site for SSL (https://) and not for the issue I'm having...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site probably is configured to  immediately 302-redirect http requests to https.

What happens if you hit that site directly from your browser at http://www.example_2.com/ ? does it also bounce to https?

There is some chance your example_2.com site has enabled strict transport security.  Read this.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet

A lot of people are using links of the form

```
 href="//www.example_2.com"
```

instead of

```
href="http://www.example_2.com"
```

these days to avoid this sort of confusion, and avoid mixed-content complaints. You might want to consider that. It's especially useful when you pull stuff from content delivery networks.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the article and try the `//www.example_2.com` to avoid mixed-content.